# How to convert dynamic JSON string to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, json, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a php web page returning json string. json string is like this .

```
   {
   "employees": [
   {
  "fname": "sdsdsd",
  "lname": "sdsd",
  "phone": "sdsd",
  "gender": "female",
  "dob": "1990-03-11",
  "address": "03",
  "nic": "erer",
  "email": "erererer",
  "empid": "ererere",
  "designation": "sdsds",
  "qualifications": "dsds"
 }
 ]

   }
```

this is a dynamic page (values can change). i want to display these strings in a jquery mobile listview. please tell me how should my javascript function looks like..

Comment: well it should start with `<script>` something goes here and end with `</script>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051227/how-to-populate-a-jquery-mobile-listview-with-json-data

Comment: you should return the value as JSON from your AJAX call, then it is as simple as var json_obj = ajax_result;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append extra an `[` and `]` to the beginning and end of the string. This will make it an array.

jQuery:

```
var json = '{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}';
var jsonArray = $.parseJSON('[' + json + ']');
```

JavaScript:

```
var jsonArray = eval('(' + json + ')');
```

[Here is Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vR3y6/)