# jQuery Mobile: Can't retrieve JSON data to populate list on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

I'm only new to jQuery Mobile so I was unsure of what terminology to use in my search so this might be a duplicate.

I am trying to create a simple list app using jQuery Mobile and JSON but I can not seem to retrieve the data from my JSON file. I got my code from [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051227/how-to-populate-a-jquery-mobile-listview-with-json-data) which [had this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/52Haa/) and I am almost sure I have copied it correctly but when I open it on my localhost there are no list items  populated to my first 'page'.

I am really new to this so I would very much appreciate any explanation to your answers and any help at all!

Console Errors are:

- jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 GET localhost/ListApp/html/JSON/list_data.json 404 (Not Found)
- VM1411:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : on my jquery mobile js files

Here us my code so far:

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>LIST APP</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet"href="../CSS/stylesheet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link ref="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/bootstrap.min.css"/>


    <script src="../JS/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.min.css"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css"></script>
    <script src="../JS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/listApp.js"></script>


</head>

 <body>
<div data-role="page" id="filterPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
         <h1>List App</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="mainList" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="false">
            <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading">Names</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>  


    <div data-role="page" id="secondaryDetails">
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        </div>            
    </div>

</body>   

</html>
```

## JSON:

```
var info = [{
        "id": 89,
        "age": 35,
        "name": "Amelia Mcknight",
        "gender": "female",
        "company": "Colaire",
        "email": "ameliamcknight@colaire.com",
        "phone": "+1 (949) 563-3174",
        "address": "107 Nevins Street, Titanic, Georgia, 5057"
}, {
        "id": 88,
        "age": 30,
        "name": "Briggs Robinson",
        "gender": "male",
        "company": "Otherway",
        "email": "briggsrobinson@otherway.com",
        "phone": "+1 (804) 517-2941",
        "address": "897 Grand Street, Madaket, Ohio, 2793"
},
];
```

## JQUERY:

```
$.getJSON("../JSON/list_data.json", function(info){

$(document).on("pageinit", "#mainList", function () {

    var li = "";
    $.each(data, function (i, name) {
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + name.name + '</a></li>';

    $("#mainList").append(li).promise().done(function () {

        $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#secondaryDetails").data("info", info[this.id]);
          index.html#secondaryDetails

            $.mobile.changePage("#secondaryDetails");
        });


        $(this).listview("refresh");

});

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#secondaryDetails", function () {

    var info = $(this).data("info");

    var info_view = "";

    for (var key in info) {
        info_view += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 75%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
    }

    $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
});
    });

     });
});
});
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in console?

Comment: Does `list_data.json` actually contain `var info =` as shown? (If so that's not valid JSON.) Also the `"address"` property of the first item is missing a closing `"`.

Comment: Are you really populating the html with the data ??? because you are not using the Json info for populating instead you are using data.name ...you should use info.name

Comment: @nnnnnn It does have `var info =` as shown because that is how it is displayed on the  example I copied from? But I have changed it to `{
"info": [ {
        ...
}, {
        ...
}, ]}` and still no luck

Comment: @user2181397 The console says "Uncaught TypeError: can not read property of type error null" is also says there are syntax errors in the jquery files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

**HTML file :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>LIST APP</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
 
$(document).on("pageinit", "#filterPage", function () {
$.getJSON("../JSON/list_data.json", function(info){
    var li = "";
    $.each(info, function (i, name) {
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + name.name + '</a></li>';

    $("#mainList").append(li).promise().done(function () {

        $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#secondaryDetails").data("info", info[this.id]);
          

            $.mobile.changePage("#secondaryDetails");
        });


        $(this).listview("refresh");
 });
});
});
});



$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#secondaryDetails", function () {

    var info = $(this).data("info");

    var info_view = "";

    for (var key in info) {
        info_view += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 75%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
    }

    $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
});
 
 
 </script>


</head>

 <body>
<div data-role="page" id="filterPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
         <h1>List App</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="mainList" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="false">
            <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading">Names</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>  


    <div data-role="page" id="secondaryDetails">
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        </div>            
    </div>

</body>   

</html>
```

**JSON file :**

```html
[{
        "id": 89,
        "age": 35,
        "name": "Amelia Mcknight",
        "gender": "female",
        "company": "Colaire",
        "email": "ameliamcknight@colaire.com",
        "phone": "+1 (949) 563-3174",
        "address": "107 Nevins Street, Titanic, Georgia, 5057"
}, {
        "id": 88,
        "age": 30,
        "name": "Briggs Robinson",
        "gender": "male",
        "company": "Otherway",
        "email": "briggsrobinson@otherway.com",
        "phone": "+1 (804) 517-2941",
        "address": "897 Grand Street, Madaket, Ohio, 2793"
}
]
```

Comment: When I try to run this code locally it doesn't open and just keeps loading. I think I am coding it wrong when I am trying to move the JSON data to its own file. Can you write the code as it would be if I had one .json file for my data and one .js file not just one file?? Also, what do you mean "..change the javaScript src link in html page." Have I the wrong js versions?

Comment: Means you want without `.js` file and one `.json` file

Comment: I meant this line `<script src="js/js.js"></script>` .I told to change to your `.js` file's URL

Comment: I'm not following. I already have a js file called `"../JS/listApp.js"` do I need to make another one? I want to keep my `"../JS/listApp.js"` and my `"../JSON/list_data.json"` files separately and not in one file, just like my question.

Comment: Only use this html code and put the Json data in `list_data.json` file

Comment: You have internet connection in the device where you testing this code?

Comment: Yes I have internet connection. I just don't know why the code isn't parsing for me. In your JSON snippet you don't add the variable `"info"` but you refer to it in your javascript. Is that an error?

Comment: If you click the "Run Snippet" on the html code it says an error that is the same error I am getting when opening it through local host.

Comment: This code will not work here.but if you put the `html code` in html page and `Json code` in the json file it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121532/discussion-between-cigarette-unicorn-and-homen).

Answer (score 0):

Add some error checking to your JSON call as suggested in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

```
$.getJSON( "../JSON/list_data.json", function(info){
  // your function
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });
```

and see if JSON data is loaded correctly. Also, check the console for error messages.

Comment: Do I add this just underneath `$.getJSON( "../JSON/list_data.json", function(info)`?? If so I am getting none of these console.log messages in my console. The console says "Uncaught TypeError: can not read property of type error null" is also says there are syntax errors in the jquery files.

Comment: Ok so I fixed an error and now I am getting the messages 'error' and 'complete'. There is also another error saying " jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/ListApp/html/JSON/list_data.json 404 (Not Found) 

Why does is say ListApp/html/JSON?? Should it not just be straight into JSON?

Comment: @cigarette_unicorn I updated the fail function so that it shows the error message on the console. From that you should be able to see what is wrong and correct it

Answer (score 0):

your JSON is wrong ....Please check the Correct JSON now .. you missed the ending Quotes in the JSON object. The correct JSON should be

```
var info = [{
            "id": 89,
            "age": 35,
            "name": "Amelia Mcknight",
            "gender": "female",
            "company": "Colaire",
            "email": "ameliamcknight@colaire.com",
            "phone": "+1 (949) 563-3174",
            "address": "107 Nevins Street, Titanic, Georgia, 5057"
    }, {
            "id": 88,
            "age": 30,
            "name": "Briggs Robinson",
            "gender": "male",
            "company": "Otherway",
            "email": "briggsrobinson@otherway.com",
            "phone": "+1 (804) 517-2941",
            "address": "897 Grand Street, Madaket, Ohio, 2793"
    },
    ];
```

you have lot of syntax Errors too in you JS implementation that too Syntax Errors.Please check the correct Implementations after

```
$.getJSON(info, function(info){

$(document).on("pageinit", "#mainList", function () {

    var li = "";
    $.each(data, function (i, name) {
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + name.name + '</a></li>';

    $("#mainList").append(li).promise().done(function () {

        $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#secondaryDetails").data("info", info[this.id]);

            $.mobile.changePage("#secondaryDetails");
        });


        $(this).listview("refresh");

});

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#secondaryDetails", function () {

    var info = $(this).data("info");

    var info_view = "";

    for (var key in info) {
        info_view += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 75%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
    }

    $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
});
    });

     });
});
```

Please try to check console in you browser for errors .

Comment: I have copied your code in but it still isn't working. The console says "Uncaught TypeError: can not read property of type error null" is also says there are syntax errors in the jquery files.